# Bootstrap/wordpress function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried a lot of methods before asking here. The stylesheets are not loading at all, I really don't know what is wrong with the code...

Thanks!

function.php

```
<?php

function styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('ionicons', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/ionicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awsome', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/font-awsome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancybox', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('animations', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/animations.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'styles' );



?>
```

header.php

```
<title></title>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE CSS -->

<?php wp_head();?>

<!-- HTML5 Shiv and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

i've tried like this, still no success

```
<?php

function style() {
 wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/bootstrap.css');

 wp_enqueue_style('style' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `action` should be `admin_enqueue_scripts` not `wp_enqueue_style`.
Code will be:

```
function styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('ionicons', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/ionicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awsome', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/font-awsome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancybox', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('animations', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/animations.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());


}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'styles' );
?>
```

Also, you doing wrong with `get_stylesheet_uri` and `get_template_directory_uri`. Read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code without any function:

```
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('ionicons', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/ionicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awsome', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/font-awsome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancybox', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('animations', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/animations.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
```